# What parts of JavaScript and jQuery are essential reading for Web Designers

Tags: javascript, website-design, jquery

As a web designer, how should I go about learning javascript and jquery? I would like to avoid duplicating my efforts and focus on whats important.

I am very much confused and need a place to start.

Comment: watch these vids. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/conversation/learn-javascript-videos  all I can say....

Comment: the videos posted in the link above.. if viewed top to bottom, should give you a good start in javascript.

Comment: **ProTip:** if you are rooted in your 'designers don't need to know  Javascript' mentality... then learn some basics... prototype your site using jQuery - then pass it to a developer to write properly with your design/UI

Comment: @rlemon         I am a junior web designer aspiring to be an USER INTERFACE DESIGNER, Am I going on right way?

Comment: will you be sending developers mockups or will you be developing the production site? Designers have no place writing production code... really.. and developers generally arn't the best designers or UX guys (albeit there are a lot of people who are both). If you choose to only be the 'designer' then you can skimp by with copy and pasting plugins and such... but don't expect people to like the code you write...

Answer (score 2):

The problem with front end is you need to know a little bit of everything!

If you have strong HTML and CSS skills already then forget jQuery for now, grab one of the learn Javascript in 21 days books, and really get to know it.

You won't have much success if you try and do everything at once.

Comment: +1 to "Forget jQuery" for now at least... once you understand some of the basics of Javascript language and how it interacts with the DOM via the DOM API then jQuery should be much easier to understand and you'll be able to debug much faster (imo).

Comment: @toomanyairmiles    still, what would one expect for a web designer to know about javascript and/or jquery?

Comment: DOM API ... this is how Javascript interacts with the page.

Comment: @jitendra111 depends where you see your career going really, I would say if you want to be a web designer then you should learn javascript full stop - it's the basis of everything web designers do these days.

Comment: @ toomanyairmiles     thank you. I am a junior web designer aspiring to be an USER INTERFACE DESIGNER, Am I going on right way?

Comment: @jitendra111 Yes, I'm a senior in that field, hit up the javascript and build yourself an interesting web application with it and you'll begin to develop the understanding you need. Don't worry about the rest for now, nail down the basics.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles      tHANK YOU :) YOU BOOST UP MY CONFIDENCE

Comment: @jitendra111 good luck, don't forget to use stackoverflow when you run into coding problems.

Answer (score 1):

http://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/

Learn this especially for webdesign things. But u have to learn javascript too, its needed sometimes. Also if u only do webDesign

Comment: well considering jQuery is a Javascript library... it is **Always** needed.

Comment: "especially for webdesign" - effects, css-change-thingy and all the other little things

Comment: I know, I am just dropping little tid-bits for the OP. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same situation. So far I have been trying to learn both at the same time but gave up with Query for a while to focus on Javascript. It is really tough as I come from a design background and haven't done a Computer Science degree or know any other programming languages. I can't stomach the video tutorials...something about over excited guys called tod who are 'super excited' to teach me drives me insane. Anyways, what I have found useful is:

- http://www.codecademy.com/
- [http://www.amazon.com/jQuery-Novice-Ninja-Earle-Castledine/dp/0980576857](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0980576857)
- http://eloquentjavascript.net

I found that repeating the starter tutorials on codeacademy over and over again started to get it into my head. Then when I read the books I felt less lost.